# re.split for ocr with BERT

Tags: python, split, ocr, spell-checking, bert-language-model

So I'm building an OCR software and using BERT as a post process to improve accuracy. anyway i noticed that while using `words = text.split()` BERT wouldn't handle any numbers and would remove them so I changed it to this `words = re.split('(\d+)', text)` however this seems to present a new issue as the split will always create a blank in the array if the first thing detected is a number so it would cause a crash. so i tried `words = filter(None, re.split('(\d+)', text))` however this will always filter out the first word detected if its not a number.
So my question is how do i get a split working that can skip over numbers however still detect words like usual and not have numbers discarded.

heres the code section

```
        d = SpellChecker("en_US")
        words = filter(None, re.split('(\d+)', text))
        incorrectwords = [w for w in words if not d.check(w) and w not in ignorewords]
        # using enchant.checker.SpellChecker, get suggested replacements
        suggestedwords = [d.suggest(w) for w in incorrectwords]
        # replace incorrect words with [MASK]
        for w in incorrectwords:
            text = text.replace(w, '[MASK]')
            text_original = text_original.replace(w, '[MASK]')
```

Comment: Hi @frostcalls, can you please include a sample of the expected output? Also, your issue seems to be related with spliting the string and does not have relation with BERT itself, am I right? Please update your questions with an expected output too

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.